# iTextG PDF generator won't render Persian characters

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am using [iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg) 5.5.3 to generate a Persian pdf file. So I used the following code:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfFileOutputStream);
document.open();

Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("سلام این متن برای تست است.");
BaseFont farsiFont = BaseFont.createFont("assets/fonts/BMitra.ttf", "UTF-8", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font paraFont= new Font(farsiFont);
p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
p1.setFont(paraFont);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(p1);
cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
table.addCell(cell);

document.add(table);
document.close();
```

But Persian characters aren't written in the output file. I also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683985/generating-persian-pdf-with-itext).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533331/itext-pdfptable-doesnt-show-cyrillicrussian-symbols?rq=1) I changed my code to:

```
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
BaseFont farsiFont = BaseFont.createFont("assets/fonts/BMitra.ttf", "UTF-8", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font paraFont= new Font(farsiFont);
p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
p1.setFont(paraFont);
p1.add("سلام این متن برای تست است.");
```

And it works.